# Characterize continuous functions $f : X → Y$ for which $f^{− 1} ( \{ a\} )$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Let
X
and
Y
be topological spaces and
f
:
X
→
Y
be a continuous function. Prove that
for every
a
∈
Y
the set
$f^{−1}$({a}) is a closed set. Assume that
X
is connected. Characterize all
continuous functions
f
:
X
→
Y
for which
$f^{−1}$
(
{
a
}
) is open as well.

I used the answer of [Can continuity be proven in terms of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107296/can-continuity-be-proven-in-terms-of-closed-sets) to proof the first part (for sets instead of a single element of Y). But I cannot characterize all
continuous functions.

Comment: What happens if a set is both open and closed?

Comment: For arbitrary topological spaces the claim "Prove that for every $a\in Y$ the set $f^{-1}(\{a\})$ is closed" is false. Let $X$ and $Y$ be the topological space with underlying set $\{1,2\}$ and with the indescrete topology  and let $f$ be the identity map then $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ is neither open nor closed.

Comment: @Nex: What claim are you referring to?

Comment: This is true if $Y$ is a $T_1$ space.

Comment: @Nex He's probably asumming points are closed in $Y$.

Comment: @Zircht The point of my comment is that the OP should tell us all the assumptions...

Comment: @Nex Yeah, I know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $Y$ is $T_1$, then all sets $\{a\}$ for $a \in Y$ are closed subsets, so $f^{-1}[\{a\}]$ is closed as the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function.

If there is some $a_0 \in Y$ such that $f^{-1}[\{a_0\}]$ is non-empty and open, and if $X$ is connected, then $f^{-1}[\{a_0\}]$ is closed, open and non-empty, and in a connected space this means that $f^{-1}[\{a_0\}] = X$ (otherwise the set and its complement disconnect $X$!). And this in turn is equivalent to $f$ being constant (with value $a_0$). Note that then all $f^{-1}[\{a\}]$ are open, as for $a \neq a_0$ the set is just the (open) empty set. (And if all inverse images of singletons are open, one of them at least is non-empty, and the previous applies).

Answer (score 0):

These are the functions $f:\>X\to Y$ which are constant on the connected components of $X$.

*Proof.* If $f$ is constant on the connected components of $X$ then $f^{-1}\bigl(\{a\}\bigr))$ is either empty, or a union of open components of $X$, whence open for every $a\in Y$.

Conversely: Assume that $f^{-1}\bigl(\{a\}\bigr)$ is open for every $a\in Y$. Let $\Omega$ be a component of $X$, choose a point $x_0\in \Omega$, and  put $a:=f(x_0)$. The sets
$$\Omega_0:=f^{-1}(\{a\})\cap\Omega$$
and
$$\Omega_1=\left(\bigcup_{y\in Y\setminus\{a\}} f^{-1}\bigl(\{y\}\bigr)\right)\cap\Omega$$
are open and disjoint subsets of $\Omega$ whose union  is $\Omega$. As $x_0\in\Omega_0$ it follows that $\Omega_1=\emptyset$, which then implies that $f(x)\equiv a$ on $\Omega$.